# How to Save All notifications?

Tags: notifications

I have IOS 8 and I want to know how to save ALL of my notifications.
What I mean is, I unlock the phone and then the notification disappears and I didn't read it. I have looked all over and there's no way I've found.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Notifications > Messages > Show in Notification Centre > … you can set up to 10 recent items

then all you need to do is swipe your screen from the top down & there they are [though if you've never used that before you'll probably need to clear a whole lot of other stuff first time & trim which apps actually need to be in there.]

You can't have *all* - only the last 10.